# Why doesn't flot work with a array of (x,y) values? Javascript object versus arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm creating a flot graph using some php-script. The php generates the data and uses `json_encode`to pass this data to some javascript-flot code where I parse using `jQuery.parseJson`.

I was using the `data`-array filled with (x,y) values. Plotting this doesn't seem to work. If I encapsulate the array within an object flot is plotting it without problems. Why doesn't the first method work? I've added a jsFiddle below.

```
var data = '[["201518","1"],["201519","3"],["201520","6"]]',
    data2 = '{"data":[["201518","1"],["201519","3"],["201520","6"]]}';

var set = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
    set2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data2);

var placeholder = $('#placeholder');
$.plot(placeholder, [set2.data]);
//$.plot(placeholder, set); <= not working? Why?
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dietervdf/axp7Lgxu/)

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) - in array format they must be numbers and not strings. This, however, does not seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems. First you need numbers and not strings when passing as an array (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) where it says

> Note that to simplify the internal logic in Flot both the x and y
>   values must be numbers (even if specifying time series, see below for
>   how to do this). This is a common problem because you might retrieve
>   data from the database and serialize them directly to JSON without
>   noticing the wrong type. If you're getting mysterious errors, double
>   check that you're inputting numbers and not strings.

Second (as pointed out in another answer), you need the [array] around set. The following works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '[[201518,1], [201519,3], [201520,6]]',
        data2 = '{"data":[["201518","1"],["201519","3"],["201520","6"]]}';

    var set = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
        set2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data2);

    var placeholder = $('#placeholder');
    //$.plot(placeholder, [set2.data]);
    $.plot(placeholder, [set]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an array:

```
$.plot(placeholder, [set])
// instead of `$.plot(placeholder, set)`
```